# SQL procedure: Updating a specific row to current system year

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I need to create a procedure to update a specific row to the "current year" *whatever the current year is at the time of executing the function*. It'd be ideal if this could be done without needing to specify the month or day also, allowing multiple dates to be updated to the latest year without affecting the date.

Most of the posts/results of my searches resulted in finding out how to select items with the current year, but I couldn't find anything about setting the current year (without manually entering it, or using ADD DATE).

My current table called `tblevents` is as below

```
|EventID|StartDate          |EndDate            |EventFee|  
|1      |2005-12-20 00:00:00|2005-12-20 00:00:00|350     |  
|2      |2005-12-20 00:00:00|2005-12-20 00:00:00|320     |  
|3      |2005-12-20 00:00:00|2005-12-20 00:00:00|100     |  
|4      |2005-12-20 00:00:00|2005-12-20 00:00:00|200     |  
|5      |2005-12-20 00:00:00|2005-12-20 00:00:00|650     |
```

I've first tried just executing the query just by using UPDATE to get used to it and so far I have tried many variations on

```
UPDATE `tblevents` 
SET `StartDate` = '(SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()))-12-20', `EndDate` = '(SELECT 
YEAR(CURDATE()))-12-20'
WHERE `EventID`=3;
```

and also tried this:

```
SELECT YEAR(CURDATE()) AS 'CYEAR';
UPDATE tblevents SET `StartDate` = 'CYEAR-12-05', `EndDate` = 'CYEAR-12-07'
WHERE `EventID`=3;
```

I'd love to know where I'm going wrong for the update query, as well as how I could accomplish this using a procedure.

I either receive syntax errors or the date is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the dates to the current year, you can use date operations:

```
UPDATE tblevents 
    SET StartDate = str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(curdate()), month(startdate), day(startdate)),  '%Y-%m-%d),
        endDate = str_to_date(concat_ws('-', year(curdate9)), month(enddate), day(enddate), '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE EventID = 3;
```

Comment: I had a few issues with formatting to suit the SQL version. So, I used the *Select* command to work through each part of the code until I found the "issue", thanks to your code I also managed to use it to create a procedure which was a plus. Your response answered it, thanks :)